Is it possible to define `.data`/`.bss` sections in static locations known at compile time?
Assuming I know all the system specific details of the target and can adjust arguments given to the assembler and linker.

Context
I am writing my own programming language and compiler that implements formal verification. When defining a variable (x := 2) it will define the variable (x) as a pair of integers where the first is the address and the second is the type (e.g. (i64,u64)). The type is what other languages might return from a typeof call.
An example program:
x := 2
require x = 2

At compile-time I need to evaluate that the address space of the program has 2 at x.0.
When the evaluator looks at x := 2 if I know the value of x.0 (.data x0: .doubleword 2) is 0x080017FB it can store{ 0x080017FB: 0b00000000, ..,  0x080017FF: 0b00000010 } then when it reaches require x = 2 it can easily prove this condition.
I think this can done without the location being known at compile-time but this would be more complicated and possibly a weaker proof.

The usual level of static is "the program may be loaded at some ImageBase decided by the OS, but its internal layout is not changed". Can you work with RVAs instead of actual literal addresses?

@user555045 You can still produce position-dependent binaries on most operating systems.  No need to have the OS decide on a base address.

It might be easier to model addresses as “symbol + displacement.”  Two addresses are equal if the symbol and displacement match and are not equal if symbol matches but displacement does not or if displacement matches but symbol does not.  Ordering is also only defined for displacements of the same symbol.  This'll really make things easier for you as your validation is no longer dependent on the arbitrary choice of the linker when laying out your binary in memory.

@fuz fixed base address would be an unusual level of static

@user555045 No, not at all.  With position-dependent binaries, the binary can chose an arbitrary load address for each of its segments.  While the linker script supplied by your toolchain has a default, you can override this just fine.

Yes you can do what you're asking with a custom linker script, at least on Linux and probably other mainstream OSes.  But modern systems optionally randomize the base address of the executable's segments (fixed relative to each other, there's only one random number for all static code/data from the executable, although  the stack is randomized separately.)  This is a security measure so things like overwriting a return address via a buffer overflow don't have known locations for snippets of machine code.  It's also only possible for the main executable, not ELF shared libs on GNU/Linux.

It seems to me that you should be able to do what you want in terms of offsets from the "image base" (e.g. the start of the .text section) - that's an equally useful way to keep track of what's where in static storage.

@fuz I obviously know that you can do that, but it's not the normal thing to do and it would be rude of a whole language to demand it.

@fuz apparently /DYNAMICBASE:NO is not even supported for all platforms, namely not on ARM, ARM64, and ARM64EC

@user555045 Could be that Windows is defective in this regard.  Please consider that other platforms are different.

I can make it work with RVAs or "symbol+displacement", but this introduces a level of indirection that complicates the process (e.g. proving "x+2" and "y+2" point to different addresses) (especially when interacting with later heap allocations). I'm trying to see if there is a way to avoid this complication. I was thinking since to the operating system they are all virtual addresses it should be do-able.
It is easiest if the base address of all sections can be known, then becomes progressively more complicated as more things are dynamic.
